# compare pandas dataframes with different lengths

Tags: pandas

I have two dataframes of different lengths and I need to add a column to the first one with filtered values, e.g.

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Object':['cup', 'brick', 'board', 'stone'], 'id':[2, 8, 9, 6]})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Thing':['cup', 'board'], 'color':['blue', 'grey']})
```

and I want to create

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Thing':['cup', 'board'], 'color':['blue', 'grey'], 'id':[2, 9]})
```

All methods I tried to use complained about different lengths.

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish your task by using the `merge` operation in pandas as follows:

```
In [16]: df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Object':['cup', 'brick', 'board', 'stone'], 'id':[2, 8, 9, 6]})

In [17]: df1
Out[17]: 
  Object  id
0    cup   2
1  brick   8
2  board   9
3  stone   6

In [18]: df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Thing':['cup', 'board'], 'color':['blue', 'grey']})

In [19]: df2
Out[19]: 
   Thing color
0    cup  blue
1  board  grey

In [20]: df = df2.merge(df1, left_on='Thing',right_on='Object', how='inner')

In [21]: df
Out[21]: 
   Thing color Object  id
0    cup  blue    cup   2
1  board  grey  board   9
```

and then drop the column (`df.drop('Object', inplace=True)`) that you don't need. For more details look at the official documentation [here.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) Also, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101) to see how you can use merge and join operations in pandas to do all kinds of dataframe manipulations!